# Default location for storing bitlocker key

Tags: windows-7, security, bitlocker

I messed up big time.

I had one of my drives encrypted using bitlocker. I remember that I haven't copied the recovery key to a usb device. Now I also have forgotten the password since I didn't used the laptop for a few month.

Hence my only chance to getting my data back is to locate the file for recovery key.

Since I remember backing up the key to local machine and not a flash drive, I have some hope. But the fact is I am not able to locate the recovery key file.

Can someone please help me. I just need the default location for storing the recovery key.

Answer (score 4):

The Bitlock keys can be found in [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959046.aspx) (HKLM).

1. Open the Registry Editor (press [image] + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `regedit`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. Navigate to:

   ```
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\FVE
   ```
3. Look for the values of `DefaultRecoveryFolderPath`.

<sub>[`Source`](http://sawyerfam06.blogspot.com.br/2008/09/bitlocker-registry-keys.html)</sub>

See also [BitLocker Recovery Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn383583.aspx#BKMK_AppendixB) for more information.

Comment: I checked it. I have no directory under 'Microsoft' called 'FVE'. The only ones listed are :- Cryptography, Netlogon, PeerDist, Peernet, SystemCertificates, Windows, WindowsNT. So no luck there.